# aws git-remote-codecommit operation error (GRC)

Tags: python-3.x, git, boto3, aws-codecommit, jmespath

I hit this error when using git with a remote codecommit repo using GRC protocol.

```
git fetch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/meh/.local/bin/git-remote-codecommit", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3079, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 888, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1' distribution was not found and is required by botocore
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case other hit this issue.

I'm using oracle linux 8 install atm, and installed python3 and and awscli + boto from an rpm.
for me the fix was to install jmespath from yum. It's not obvious at first but this is part of the python package family. to fix the issue you need to install the additional python3-jmespath package.

Example:

```
sudo yum install python3-jmespath.noarch
```